# Progress bar Não funciona

Tags: java, android

Gente Tenho duas thread, uma que acessa a webview com o url e outra responsável por progressbar, porem o progress bar não esta executando. O que pode ser e como arrumar ?

```
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Network;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class ConectActivity extends Activity {


    private WebView webView;
    private ProgressBar progress;

    public  boolean verificaConexao() {
        boolean conectado;
        ConnectivityManager conectivtyManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (conectivtyManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                && conectivtyManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                && conectivtyManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
            conectado = true;
        } else {
            conectado = false;
        }
        return conectado;
    }

    Boolean  conect;
    String  url = "http://google.com";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_conect);
        // *** roda qnd abre - Augusto Furlan ***
        conect = verificaConexao();
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
        //webView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
        webView.setVisibility(webView.GONE);

        WebSettings ws = webView.getSettings();
        ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        ws.setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());



        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                SystemClock.sleep(10000);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        showWebView();
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(conect == true) {
                    webView.loadUrl(url);
                } else {webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/not-found.html");;}

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        showWebView();
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
        }



    private void showWebView() {
        webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade, você possui 3 threads. Na segunda thread que você cria (lembrando que a Main Thread, responsável pela interface, é criada automaticamente ao se criar o processo do aplicativo, por isso essa é a segunda que você explicitamente criou), essa:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(conect == true) {
                    webView.loadUrl(url);
                } else {webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/not-found.html");;}

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        showWebView();
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
        }
```

Você está chamando o método que remove o progress, esse:

```
 private void showWebView() {
        webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Tendo em vista que essa thread é criada no onCreate da Activity (quando ela ainda não está visível), você provavelmente está removendo o progress antes mesmo de você poder ver ele na tela.

Comment: amigo, nao deu erro no codigo, mas continua sem exibir o pre-loader

Comment: o codigo atual esta http://pastebin.com/ZryMVMJX

Comment: Eu sei que não está com erro, pois realmente não há erros. O problema, é que você remove o progressBar da tela, logo na inicialização da activity. Então você não chega nem a ver ele. Comente o seguinte código:
`// progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);` E então você verá que o progress será mostrado na tela. Desde que no xml ele esteja marcado como visível.

Comment: ao comentar o progress fica eternamente rodando.

Comment: Amigo resolveu, obg

Comment: Que bom que resolveu. Qualquer coisa, estamos ai!